# Using an ANN to calculate a position vector's length and the angle between it and the x-axis

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm new to neural networks and trying to get the hang of it by solving the following task:

Given a semi circle which defines an area **above the x-axis**, I would like to teach an ANN to output the length of a vector pointing to any position within that area. In addition, I would also like to know the angle between it and the x-axis.

I thought of this as a classical example of supervised learning and used Backpropagation to train a feed-forward network. The network is built by two Input-, two Output-, and variable amount of Hidden-neurons organised in a variable amount of hidden layers.

My training data is a random and unsorted sample of points within that area and the respective desired values. The coordinates of the points serve as the input of the net while I use the calculated values to minimise the error.

However, even after thousands of training iterations and empirical changes of the networks topology, I am unable to produce results with an error below ~0.2 (Radius: 20.0, Topology: 2/4/2).

Are there any obvious pitfalls I'm failing to see or does the chosen approach just not fit the task? Which other network types and/or learning techniques could be used to complete the task?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use variable amounts of hidden layers, I would use just one.

Then, I wouldn't use two output neurons, I would use two separate ANNs, one for each of the values you're after. This should do better, since your outputs aren't clearly related in my opinion.

Then, I would experiment with number of hidden neurons between 2 and 10 and different activation functions (`logistic` and `tanh`, maybe ReLUs).

After that, do you scale your data? It might be worth scaling both your inputs and outputs. Sigmoid units return small numbers, so it is good if you can adapt your outputs to be small as well (in `[-1 , 1]` or `[0, 1]`). For example, if want your angles in degrees, divide all of your targets by `360` before training the ANN on them. Then when the ANN returns a result, multiply it by `360` and see if that helps.

Finally, there are a number of ways to train your neural network. Gradient descent is the classic, but probably not the best. Better methods are conjugate gradient, BFGS etc. See here for [optimizers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) if you're using python - even if not, they might give you an idea of what to search for in your language.